Server side processing cell styling
I am requesting some help on my server-side processing jQuery script
What I need is to,

Add td class,
Get cell values
And change the cell styling

Below is my script I have tried.
Am getting this error,
Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#contact-detail").dataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "scpp.php",
                "type": "POST",
                "dataType": "json"
            },

            rowCallback: function(row, data, index) { // get cells

                $('#td_id').addClass('td_style'); // add td class

                var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");  // help to select the current row.

                if (data[0]) { // for first cell
                    var col1 = $(row) currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text(); // find first cell value
                    $(this).html('<a href="order.php?d=' + col1 + '" role="button" class="btn"> <span class="spinn" role="status"></span>>' + col1 + '</a>') // make it look like this
                }
                if (data[1]) { // for second cell
                    var col2 = $(row) currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text(); // find second cell value
                    $(this).html('<img src="img/' + col2 + '" class="image" alt="Trulli">') // make it look like this
                }
                if (data[2]) { // for third cell
                    var col3 = $(row) currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").text(); // find third cell value
                    $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i> ' + col3 + ' ') // make it look like this
                }
            }
        });
    }); <
</script>


Take a look at the lines like var col1 = $(row) currentRow.find(..., you can see a semicolon (and a line-break) is missing,

Yes i have put the ; semicolon on those 3 col1 col2  col3 , but am still getting that error  Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier

Then no repro with the given code.

do like this for all td code :  var td1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)"); var col1 = td1.text(); // find first cell value td1.html('<a href="order.php?d=' + col1 + '" role="button" class="btn"> <span class="spinn" role="status"></span>>' + col1 + '</a>');.  Also $(row) currentRow. seems to be a TYPO mistake in your question code

`  $(document).ready(function () {
$("#dd").dataTable({
"processing": true,
"serverSide": true,
"ajax": {
"url": "kkk.pl",
"type": "POST",
"dataType":"json"
},
var currentRow=$(this).closest("tr");
var td1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)");
var col1 = td1.text(); // find first cell value
td1.html(' >' + col1 + '');
        });
    });`


am getting this error  Uncaught SyntaxError: missing : after property id
